# Отправка zip архива POST запросом(bash script)

Tags: linux, bash

Есть архив, находящийся в папке: */work/test/arc.zip
Необходимо отправить этот архив POST запросом на сервер - необходим пример команды.

Пробовал:

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" @*/work/test/arc.zip **http//urlСервера**
```

Comment: Через `curl` не пробовали?

Comment: @PeterSamokhin, пробовал, мне нужен работающий скрипт

Comment: @bsuart так покажите, как вы пробывали.

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -F "myFieldName=@/work/test/arc.zip" https://сервер/upload.php
```

Подробнее в мануале, который встроен в вашу операционную систему:

```
man curl
```

Comment: это будет GET запрос

Comment: Да ну? А вот мануал пишет, что не будет.

Comment: ссылку на мануал

Comment: Он встроен в вашу операционную систему и вызывается так: man curl

Comment: *(HTTP) This lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has  pressed  the  submit  button. This  causes  curl to POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC 2388.* и далее по тексту...